# Regular expression on JavaScript how to add whole word search and case insensitive in positive look behind and positive look ahead

Tags: javascript, regex

**I need to make some adjustments on a project which is about searching whole words and changing their styles in a paragraph.    There are similar questions online but I found the answers are still not working in this case.**

```
//text contains words
const text=" there are some keywords that need to be found and changed. key is a different word."
//words need to be whole search
const words=["keywords","key","need"] 
//split the text by words, after the split if the element match words then change style  
const ChangeStyle=(text, words)=>{
  return ({text.split(new RegExp(`(?<=${words.join("|")})|(?=${words.join("|")})`))
.map((element)=>{ return words.include(element)?(<span style={{color:red}}>{element}</span>):
{element}
})})
}
```

The issue is that after use all words from words array to do the split work. even the "keywords" in the text will split by the "key", split into "key" and "words".so that "keywords" itself will never be found and change the style.   In this case only "key" and "need" will be found in the text and changed style.I try to sort the words array and the result is the same.

In regular expression "(\bword[\s.])" I think can do the whole word search job (find the "word" that starts with word boundary, end with a dot or empty space).

**In this case if I want to keep the split logic, how can I combine that "\bword[\s.]" into the above regExp so that it will do whole word split and case insensitive?**

Comment: Making all the text bold makes it hard to read

Comment: FYI @timdown has this awesome rangy project. It is set up to work with elements and selection ranges so not really applicable to this question. But if you never want to style based on selection ranges, I highly recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a `replace` instead of a `split' it will replace one word after the next. Working example:

```js
const text = " there are some keywords that need to be found and changed. key is a different word.";
const words = ["keywords","key","need"];
const ChangeStyle = (text, words) => {
  let re = new RegExp('\\b(' + words.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g');
  return text.replace(re, function(m) {
    return '<span style="{{color:red}}">' + m + '</span>';
  });
}
console.log(ChangeStyle(text, words));
```

Output:

`there are some <span style="{{color:red}}">keywords</span> that <span style="{{color:red}}">need</span> to be found and changed. <span style="{{color:red}}">key</span> is a different word.`

Explanation of regex:

- `'\\b('` - word boundary (notice escaped backslash in string definition) and start of group
- `words.join('|')` - your words OR-combined
- `')\\b'` - end of group and word boundary
- `'g'` - global flag to replace all occurrences